# flask-admin and self-Referential many-to-many relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a structure of the sqlalchemy model of similar to [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship).

How I can use [AJAX key loading](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs) for these relations in flask-admin?
I have the table with ~300k records and when I push "Create" tab - free memory on my computer is ends, browser does not respond. When I haven't records or records much less than 300 - no problem.
I have not found how to solve this question.

Models:

```
part_analog = Table(
    "part_analog", Base.metadata,
    Column("master", Integer, ForeignKey("part.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("slave", Integer, ForeignKey("part.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Part(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'part'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = Column(String(30), default=None)
    brand = Column(String(30), default=None)
    description = Column(Text())
    category = Column(String(40), default=None)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    analogs = relationship(
        "Part", secondary=part_analog,
        primaryjoin=id == part_analog.c.master,
        secondaryjoin=id == part_analog.c.slave,
    )
```